# "N-free" permutations of (0,...,n-1) and pairs of orthogonal vectors in n-space

Tags: linear-algebra

If you click on the "puzzle" button here:

https://www.thesyntacticretina.com/

you will see a SEEMINGLY "mysterious" linear-algebraic "puzzle" for which John Burkardt has kindly provided the solution (to see this solution, click on the "solution" button.)

Question:

Are there any cases of this result other than those arising from "N-free" permutations of (0,...,n-1), or from "N-free" posets corresponding to "N-free" permutations?

Comment: The solution says so right in it. The only thing that is necessary of the vectors is that they have the same norm. Two permutations of $1$ to $n$ is just one way of guaranteeing it. And although I haven't translated the solution to check it, I suspect that it works by doubling that 45 degree rotation.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - Thanks for taking the time to respond, and I am sorry that my question was unclear.  What I am looking for is another case where the "same norm" condition is satisfied by some set of vectors that DON'T arise from a permutation, but DO arise in some already known pure or applied context not related in any way to permuatations.  If you can think of any such case, I would be very grateful to know of it.

Comment: Getting two vectors with the same norm is very easy. Just pick two non-zero vectors at random and divide each by its norm. All unit vectors have norm $1$. Vectors with the same norm arise in any context where the norm of a vector is defined.

Comment: Can you think of a case where you don't divide each by its norm in order to satisfy the condition trivially ?  (Again, a case that arises in some known context . . . )  Thank you for your patience here - I hope I'm not irritating you at this point . . .

Comment: Usually when you have multiple vectors, you want them to be the same length. Converting vectors to be the same length is an easy and normal thing to do. *Anywhere* you see norms, you will find vectors of the same length commonly used. It is not some odd or mysterious or unusual thing. It is quite common.

Comment: So for example, scaling one vector up or down to match the length of another (instead of scaling both to 1)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69241/discussion-between-david-halitsky-and-paul-sinclair).