# Hyperboloids of one sheet, hyperbolic paraboloids, and Hilbert's famous "three skew lines"

Tags: differential-geometry, quadratic-forms, quadrics

One of Hilbert's many deceptively simple observations involved generators of hyperboloids of one sheet and hyperbolic paraboloids:

Three skew lines always define a one-sheeted hyperboloid, except in the case where they are all parallel to a single plane but not to each other. In this case, they determine a hyperbolic paraboloid (Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen 1999, p. 15).

This fact suggest the possibility that interesting transforms of these two surfaces into one another might be statable in terms of operations on triples of skew-lines.

Are there such transforms?

If not, is there some particular a priori reason why they can't exist?

I'm not asking this question idly, but rather as a follow-on to this question:

[Suppose it can be shown that any right(left)-regular finite-state grammar implicitly generates a "hypar"" surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537513/suppose-it-can-be-shown-that-any-rightleft-regular-finite-state-grammar-implic)